# Which encoding to open utf-8 csv file in Python which opens correctly in Excel with Windows (ANSI)

Tags: python, utf-8

I have a database export in csv which is `UTF8` encoded.
When i open it in Excel, i have to choose `Windows (ANSI)` at opening in order to see special characters correctly displays (é, è, à for instance).
If i use Python pandas to open csv file specifying `UTF8` encoding, it does not seem to get correctly decoded (é,è,à characters are not displayed correctly):

```
StŽphanie
FrŽdŽrique
GŽraldine
```

How should i correctly read this file with Python pandas ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This encoding is Windows-1252, referred to as `"cp1252"` by Python. ANSI is a misnomer; it's completely unrelated to the organisation.

Try:

```
with open("filepath.csv", encoding="cp1252") as f:
    pandas.read_csv(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually to use `latin1` encoding in my case:

```
Stéphanie
Frédérique
Géraldine
```